# Passing a struct to a function results in nested struct

Tags: coldfusion, struct, coldfusion-9, cffunction

When I pass a struct to a function that is expecting a struct, the function is nested inside another struct.

For example:

```
function getAnswerFromSO(struct question=StructNew()) {
   writeDump(arguments.question);
}
```

Calling`getAnswerFromSO(question=myStruct);` results in

```
question {
  myStruct = {
     text = 'foo',
     subj = 'bar',
     user = 1 }
};
```

** Obviously, this is not what a `cfdump` output looks like, but it illustrates the issue just the same.

Is there a way to prevent this nesting?

Comment: How are you defining myStruct? When I tried it, it worked as expected. This is CF10 though. http://pastebin.com/V8eVgW1x

Comment: I'm a fool. I was creating the struct like so: myStruct { mystruct.text = 'foo',mystruct.subj='bar',mystruct.user=1 };

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Ray's example works on CF9 as well.